# Import product with dataflow with cron

Tags: import, magmi

I need to import everyday a csv file product. I already have this file.

I want to automate this process with cron.

How i can make this without magmi?

Thanks
Alessandro

Comment: If you are technical person see answer here : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12621/howto-setup-cronjob-to-automatically-start-a-import-profile/12628#12628 Hope it will help

Comment: just create a php code to fetch the csv, loop through it and import them back to magento programatically http://inchoo.net/magento/programming-magento/programatically-manually-creating-simple-magento-product/ Make this php file to run everyday via cron job. Simple.

Comment: for some project i used this way, but now i world like to import with dataflow